# Перенос строки. Как сделать расстояние после переноса

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordwrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
    counter-reset: example figure issue;
    /* Layout */    
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    /* Typography */
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: Calibri light;
    font-size: 8pt;
    widows: 2;
    orphans: 2;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    text-align-last: right;
    hyphens: auto;

    /* Colors */
    color: black;   
}
```

Как сделать чтобы слова переносились не целиком, а по буквах? И перенесённое предложение начиналось за определённое растояние от края. ( 10mm например ).

---

Проблема не в том чтобы сделать перенос, а чтобы перенесённая строка начиналась не под цифрами, а под началом верхней строки. Можно как-то выставить расстояние для перенесённых строк по типу 15mm? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: непонятен изначальный код. Покажите html

Answer (score 1):

Вот человек в IE работает! Чудеса!

```
overflow-wrap: break-word
```

А отступ от края получается другими средствами. Например каждый абзац оборачивается в тег

```
<p>текст</p>
```

А если уж создаем pdf файл, то совсем другие принципы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]